# Different height of rows in grid

Tags: grid, row, height

How can I make a the same gaps between divs, when I have different height of rows?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84zQd.jpg)

I tried use: grid-template-rows: masonry; grid-template-columns: masonry; and grid-auto-rows: min-content; but it not working